# UIDatePicker: How to call a function if no value was changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

I have a question concerning a UIDatePicker:

```
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

This will call my method "datePickerValueChanged:" but only if, well, a value got changed.
But how can I call that method if nothing on the UIDatePicker was changed?

Answer (score 0):

When do you want to call the method? (or when do you want it to be called?)

If you keep a reference to your date picker object, you can always call the 'datePickerValueChanged' action method directly from within your controller object or any other object that has a reference to your controller object.  You can also interrogate the date picker at any time if you have a handle to it, via its date property, to find out which date is showing.